# How to load data in chunks in a datatable without server side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datatables

In IE 8, for datatable I am getting Stop running script error when data size is huge, I don't want to go with server side processing as it is expensive. I am able to get the data to client side. error is coming when data is getting assigned to datatable.

Comment: go for server side processing, which will be even better for future..
it will be more difficult to establish data in chunks in client side.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.
Client side data processing - that will probably cause even more problems in future.

Even if you manage to load data in chunks, inserting dom elements in table is expensive operation and it's reason for "not responding". I had similar issue, tried loading in chunks, tried to found some solutions like https://github.com/stephenbez/tilava-table. At the end only good solution was pagination. Amount of data from db that can be seen at that moment like 10 by 10 lines.